# Повторное выполнение ajax

Tags: drupal, jquery, ajax

Есть ссылка .ereg-ajax. Кликаю по ней. Получаю данные и вывожу их на страницу. Почему после этого событие click по ссылке не подхватываетсяне обрабатывается?

В интернете ищу, но пока ничего хорошего не нашёл.

```
Drupal.behaviors.itdt_ereg = function (context) {

  $('.ereg-ajax').click(function(event) {
    // Get the URL without the query string - this is
    // so that we can distinguish between GET and POST
    // requests.
    var test4Url = $('.ereg-ajax').attr('href').split('?');

    // Prevent the default link action - we don't
    // want to trigger a synchronous response.
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: test4Url[0],
      cache: false,
      data: {
        'id': this.getAttribute("id"),
      },
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (data) {
        if (data.message) {
          $('#divProducts').html(data.message);
        }
      },
      error: function (xmlhttp) {
        alert('An error occured: ' + xmlhttp.status);
      }
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: Эта ссылка находится в блоке `#divProducts`?

Comment: Да. Проблема в том, что перестаёт подхватывать ссылки после того, как данные уже получены.

Comment: Вот одно из решений вашей проблемы: [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Comment: а почему бы не использовать ``this``?

    var test4Url = $(this).attr('href').split('?');

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вы хотите, чтобы работали клики по динамически созданным ссылкам, используйте функцию [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/). Если у вас не работает только что кликнутая ссылка, то, видимо, вы получаете те же данные, поэтому и не видите разницы.

Comment: Спасибо! Это как раз то, что я искал!